# SignalR protocol compatibility: 2.0 server with 1.2 client

Tags: android, asp.net, signalr

I try to build SignalR server with new 2.0 version, but will use Android client with [SignalA](https://github.com/erizet/SignalA) which supports 1.2 protocol.

I read SignalR tutorial, and it said as below in [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/upgrading-signalr-1x-projects-to-20),

> While it is encouraged to upgrade applications to SignalR 2.0, SignalR 1.x will still be supported.

Does this mean 1.2 client can be communicated with 2.0 server?

if possible, is there any drawback (lack of function) to client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, older clients work with the 2.0 server. The client will behave as it did with older versions and won't get any of the new features that newer clients use (obviously). But there's no downside.

Comment: Thanks! and I always appreciate to use SignalR :)